# create date_range in from date-string polars

Tags: python-polars

In pandas, if I have a date/string and a range, I can create a date range array with simple code:

```
date = "2023-01-12"

dates = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(date) - pd.Timedelta(days=3), periods=3, freq="D").to_list()
```

Now I'm trying to create something like this in Polars:
my initial thought is to do something like:

```
pl.date_range(pl.Datetime(date).dt.offset_by("-3d"), pl.Datetime(date), interval="1d")
```

but it doesn't word. I wonder if polars can work with one variable or if I will have to convert my date into pl.series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closest you can currently get is

```py
pl.date_range(start-dt.timedelta(days=3), start-dt.timedelta(days=1), '1d')
```

```py
In [13]: dates
Out[13]:
[Timestamp('2023-01-09 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2023-01-10 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2023-01-11 00:00:00')]

In [14]: pl.date_range(start-dt.timedelta(days=3), start-dt.timedelta(days=1), '1d')
Out[14]:
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [datetime[μs]]
[
        2023-01-09 00:00:00
        2023-01-10 00:00:00
        2023-01-11 00:00:00
]
```

Being able to specify `periods` instead of `stop` might be a reasonable feature request